# I got switched to USPS production Account still problems

Tags: usps

Last night I mailed USPS customer care executive and they had switched my account to production server in USPS.I got mail from them in which I got this message

> Dear USPS Customer,
>
> Thank you for contacting us.  Congratulations on completing your
>   testing using the U.S. Postal Services Internet Shipping Application
>   Program Interfaces (APIs).  Your profile has been updated to allow you
>   access to the Production Server. 
>   1. The Production Server URL is: http://production.shippingapis.com. For APIs calling the secure server, the URL is
>   https://secure.shippingapis.com. 
>   2. There is a line of code that refers to "shippingapitest.dll".  You'll need to remove the word "test".

In the test server code I was using

```
$usps->setServer("http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll");
```

Now I tried using this code today

```
$usps->setServer("http://production.shippingapis.com");
```

even I tried this code to get responce

```
$usps->setServer("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll");
```

Please any one used USPS in past help me.

Here is the link which helped me to test USPS in Test server[link text](http://www.marksanborn.net/php/calculating-usps-shipping-rates-with-php/)

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Now I am not getting responce not even errors

Comment: There's a question in there somewhere. Perhaps an edit to clarify would be in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called USPS last night and mentioned them about the error I was getting in the production URL they asked for my User Id and told me to try and the code was working fine.Thus don't waste time and call customer care executive